# What is the strong property attribute

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, macos

I am using the Xcode beta for developers, and am noticing some subtle differences. Among them is a new attribute for declared properties.

```
@property(strong)IBOutlet NSArrayController *arrayControl;
```

My question is: what does the strong attribute mean?? Does it replace some older one, or is it something entirely new? I have searched through google and the developer documentation and havent been able to find anything. Until i know what it is i am hesitant to use it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Really aren't supposed to talk about beta NDA stuff here...

Comment: Well, its not like im giving away corporate secrets, but yes i probably should have put this in apples dev forums

Comment: I keep seeing these "beta NDA" comments on objective c stuff. I find it hilarious that Apple feels the need to protect its objective c secrets (everyone is dying to copy objective c!), and even funnier that developers feel the need to go around bugging people about it.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It's a replacement for the `retain` attribute, as part of [Objective-C Automated Reference Counting (ARC)](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). In non-ARC code it's just a synonym for `retain`.

Answer (score 10):

A strong reference is a reference to an object that stops it from being deallocated. In other words it creates a owner relationship. Whereas previously you would do this:

```
**// Non-ARC Compliant Declaration
@property(retain) NSObject *obj;**
```

Under ARC we do the following to ensure a class instance takes an ownership interest a referenced object (i.e. so it cannot be deallocated until the owner is).

```
**// ARC Compliant Declaration
@property(strong) NSObject *obj;**
```

Answer (score 4):

As we know, we cannot release any object in an ARC-based project in iOS 5.
So when we want to retain any object for further use at a later stage and don't want ARC to remove the object from memory, then we set the property for the object as "Strong".