# Why a keyword "strong" is used on a property in non-ARC environment?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting

I just started to develop with with Xcode 4.2 and iOS5. After creating empty Tabbed application project, I have noticed that a new keyword "strong" is used on properties. I read on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701023/what-is-the-strong-property-attribute) about it being related to retain replacement in ARC environment, but it's not the case because I didn't checked "Use Automatic Reference Counting" check box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The keyword "Strong" is a synonym for "retain" in non-ARC environments.

For ARC-envs read up here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property

Comment: I wish it would be more info about that on apple dev doc. Currently, only a brief description about that might be found :(. Also, I though Apple will not push devs to use a new API but it looks like they do. What annoys be is that though ARC is not required they still bring it (at least some part) to me. IMHO, it's a little bit impolite :)

Comment: It is, but they are just trying to stay one step ahead. At least they aren't forcing you to use it yet.

Comment: it seems (at least on the latest Xcode) that if the property is of block type, `strong` does `copy` in non-ARC