# Should I be using "strong" even if I'm not using ARC?

Tags: objective-c

I know there is a lot on this question, but what I turn up is mostly related to it's unveiling and more is known about it now. So I wanted to re-ask:

Since the introduction of strong keyword, sometimes when I let XCode generate property code for me it will use "strong", other times "retain".

I personally have not adopted ARC yet, and wont' for a little while yet for learning purposes. Is there a reason that I should use either keyword in a manual memory management environment? I realize that using strong makes it easier to port to ARC if I ever do. From what I understand they are functionally the same thing.

Also, does your answer apply to weak vs assign as well (I know they are not quite the same however)?

Comment: Probably the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790407/why-a-keyword-strong-is-used-on-a-property-in-non-arc-environment?rq=1

Comment: Best to start getting used to using it now, even if you aren't using ARC in the foreseeable future.