# Strong in property and @autorelease declared differently in main what that means

Tags: iphone, ipad

I download source code from document director

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *list;


#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

I can any one tell why its showing error when i download from developer documentation the source file

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the strong property attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701023/what-is-the-strong-property-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

> It's a replacement for the `retain` attribute, as part of **Objective-C Automated Reference Counting (ARC)**. In non-ARC code it's just a synonym for `retain`.

[<sup>[Source]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701023/what-is-the-strong-property-attribute/6701058#6701058)

Your **problem** seems to be that you have an `@property` in your main.m. `@property` should be inside `@interface ... @end`

Comment: Then how to fix this issue and run my application.

Comment: if an change this to strong to retain. i do not have any issue.  its just reference to the that reference ... and when i am looking at my main class its @autorelease {  return UIapplicat.....} its showing error there has initially i load the application .. do i need to change my project setting or what ?

Comment: Are you using ios5 and have ARC turned on?

Comment: And do you have arc turned on?